# How can I convert DateTime "Thu Nov 30 19:00:00 EST 2006" to "11/30/2006"

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert DateTime "Thu Nov 30 19:00:00 EST 2006" to "11/30/2006"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Thu Nov 30 19:00:00 EST 2006", 
            "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss EST yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
}
```

The .NET framework does not support time zone abbreviations so I hard-coded "EST" into the format string (just something to be aware of if you will need to parse strings from multiple time zones).

Comment: Can you please share your idea that what should we do when given date contains other time zones?

Comment: Note that, depending on the culture, the `/`'s may be converted to `-`'s or other symbols.  If this is unwanted behavior (for instance, writing to a file with a specific format), use `dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 2):

```
mydate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

fixed the mm --> MM

Comment: You mean `MM`. (Month, not minute)

Comment: mm for minutes. There should be MM

Answer (score 1):

```
yourDate.ToString("d");
```

Comment: `d` specifies "Short Date Format", which depending on the locale, may not be `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @mlsteeves - You're right. But this is plus for globalization, isn't it?

Comment: @mlsteeves: Which, in most cases, is even better - you wouldn't want someone whose culture writes `dd/mm/yyyy` to see `mm/dd/yyyy`...

Comment: @BlueRaja Depends on what you are doing.  If you are using an API that is expected mm/dd/yyyy, then 'd' might work during testing, but as soon as you go live, and it gets into an environment where 'd' != 'mm/dd/yyyy', then things start breaking.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse() the string value than output to a custom format with dtVariable.ToString("custom string")